# Complete resource of Ngô's course notes on Algebraic Groups and Group Schemes

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, algebraic-groups, online-resources, group-schemes

I'm looking for Ngô's M2 course notes on "Groupes algébriques et schémas en groupes".

The Wayback Machine has an incomplete capture [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101115044428/http://www.math.u-psud.fr:80/%7Engo/GR.html). However, it apparently lacks chapter 1, 3, and 5.

Does anyone have the complete file? If so, please help, thanks.